# How to stack the same component when editing after writing

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```js
<Stack.Screen name="Complain" component={Complain} />
<Stack.Screen name="ComplainList" component={ComplainList} />
<Stack.Screen name="ComplainUpdate" component={Complain} />
```

How do I stack it up?  Complain === ComplainUpdate

[image]

```
<Stack.Screen name="Complain" component={Complain} />
<Stack.Screen name="ComplainList" component={ComplainList} />
<Stack.Screen name="ComplainUpdate" component={ComplainUpdate} />
```

I've copied the same components and stacked them up, but this doesn't seem like a good idea. Is there any good way?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you meant by stacking up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Stack.Screen name="Complain" component={Complain} />
<Stack.Screen name="ComplainList" component={ComplainList} />
<Stack.Screen name="ComplainUpdate" component={ComplainUpdate} />
<Stack.Screen name="ComplainAdd" component={ComplainAdd} />
```

just..  copy and paste.. i'm sorry

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).